# how efficient is checksum in case of burst errors

Tags: networking

I read it that a 16 bit checksum can detect with 100% probability a single burst error of 14 bits. However as far as I understand, checksums are 100% efficient for single bit errors only then how come is this true??? any help shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use CRC, not a simple sum.

Comment: As I know using two-dimentional checksums can detect burst errors, horizontal checksum detects single error in one row, and vertical checksum detects single error in one column, so they can detect burst errors in rows and/or columns together